How to set up the Resgrid/Core repository on a local machine?
I am trying to set up the Resgrid/Core repository on my local machine but am unable to do so.
I have followed the documentation but to no avail. I have tried doing a few things more here and there but to no use.
So can you guys please tell me how to run that project on my machine?
Thank you for helping out guys!!
